# loop over multi level lists to plot their elements in R

Tags: r, list, loops, plot

I need your help in the following:

I have multi level lists (lists in lists) and I have to plot their elements on one figure. One plot is easy and it looks like this (sorry about the non-generalized variable names)

```
plot(powerList$ch1$frequency, powerList$ch1$power, type='hist', xlim = c(0,0.001))
```

`powerList` contains other lists (`ch1`...)

I have to plot `frequency` and `power` in lists `ch1` to `ch13`.

I've tried the following:

created a vector with the channel names (second list)

```
chNames = c('ch1','ch2','ch3','ch4','ch7','ch8','ch9','ch10','ch11','ch13','ch14','ch15','ch16')
```

then I've tried to loop over it: 
first I created a 4 times 4 window

```
par(mfrow=c(4,4))

for (i in chNames){
  plot(powerList$i$frequency, powerList$i$power, type='hist', xlim = c(0,15))
}

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

I know that the code is wrong. It is just to show clearly what I want to do. Is there a way to do it simply and effectively?

Thank you

Comment: This is the simple solution I was looking for! Thank you, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Great, I'll change my response to the answer, if you wouldn't mind marking it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need to loop through the list with indexing.

```
for (i in seq_along(powerList)) { 
    plot(powerList[[i]]$frequency, powerList[[i]]$power, type='hist', xlim = c(0,15)) 
}
```